Add a custom header above an unnumbered chapter title (report document class)
I am using the report document class. When I create a (numbered) chapter, a chapter header appears above the actual chapter title. For example, \chapter{Some Title} leads to:

However, unnumbered chapters do not have headers; only the title gets printed. How can I add a custom header to an unnumbered chapter? For example, I would like to add "Prologue" as a header above the title of a prologue. A command like \chapter*[Prologue]{Prologue Title} would be nice.
I looked at the CTAN documentation for the report document class and it seems like the answer lies with the makechapterhead macro, but I'm not sure how to use it. Or perhaps creating a new chapter function/command that does not increase the chapter counter and lets the user overwrite the title header? Any help/tip welcome. Thanks!
Working example:
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Prologue Title} % <-- add "Prologue" above this chapter title
    \chapter{Some Title} % <-- automatically adds "Chapter 1" above this title
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

I ended up writing it up myself & decided to share in case it's helpful to someone else.
I basically copied the source code of the chapter function & macros (as documented in CTAN) and created my own custom functions by replacing the standard title header/label with a custom one. As in Pieter's answer, my snippet also contains hard-coded constants. Not sure if there's any way around it. Unlike his answer, however, the text formatting is the same as the base class:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% Unumbered chapter command with custom label
\newcommand{\chapterwithlabel}[2]{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \makechapterwithlabel{#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\makechapterwithlabel}[2]{%
  \vspace*{50pt} % Vertical space before the chapter label
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \huge\bfseries #1 % Chapter label
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 20\p@
  \Huge \bfseries #2 \par\nobreak % Chapter title
  \vskip 40pt
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapterwithlabel{Prologue}{Prologue Title}
\lipsum[0-3]
\chapter{Some Chapter}
\chapter*{Some Unumbered Chapter}
\end{document}

First page appearance:


You would have to redefine the \chapter command to pick up the additional "header" (I will use the term "label" instead in my solution).
And then you must redefine the chapter header layout. This can be done with the titlesec package.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\originalchapter}{}
\newcommand{\chapterlabel}{}
\let\originalchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\renewcommand\chapterlabel{}}%
      {\renewcommand\chapterlabel{#2}}%
      \originalchapter*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalchapter{#3}}
      {\originalchapter[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptername~\thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {%
    #1%
  }

  \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chapterlabel}
  {20pt}
  {%
    #1%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Default unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter*[Label]{A labeled unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[4-6]
\chapter{A numbered chapter}
\lipsum[7-9]

\end{document}



Thanks a lot for the reply! At first glance everything looks fine, but I just noticed that your code overwrite some of the constants and the formatting of the underlying "report" document class (you can see it for yourself by commenting out your modifications of the chapter command - the default chapter title position is usually a bit lower, and the label font is smaller than the title). How could you have a functionality similar to your snippet above, but without changing any of the title placement or font size of the underlying report class? Thanks again

I ended up answering my own question. Thanks a lot for the help again.
